# How to refresh the screen when the data inserted into room db in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

Am using paging 3 and i dont know how to do the in screen refresh when the data is inserted in the db.

```
**`class ContactPagingSource(private val contactDao: ContactDao, private val query: String,
                          private val sort: SortingEnum = SortingEnum.ByName) :
    PagingSource<Int, ContactLocalModel>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, ContactLocalModel>): Int? {
        return null
    }
    
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ContactLocalModel> {
        val page = params.key ?: 0
        return try {
            Timber.d("load:  + $page")
            Timber.d("onQueryTextChange ContactPagingSource $query")
            val entities = if (query.isNotBlank()) {
                contactDao.getContactPagination(
                    params.loadSize,
                    page * params.loadSize,
                    query = query,
                    isOrderByName = sort.ordinal == SortingEnum.ByName.ordinal
                )
            } else {
                contactDao.getContactPagination(
                    params.loadSize,
                    page * params.loadSize,
                    query = "%",
                    isOrderByName = sort.ordinal == SortingEnum.ByName.ordinal
                )
            }
            if (page != 0) delay(1000)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = entities,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (entities.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}`**
```

Below is my view model

```
val contacts: LiveData<PagingData<ContactLocalModel>> =
        searchPaginationName.switchMap { query ->
            Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10, enablePlaceholders = false,
                initialLoadSize = 10)) {
                ContactPagingSource(contactDao, query, sort = enumVal)
            }.liveData.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        }

    val randomContactPostFlow = Pager(
        PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            initialLoadSize = 10,
        )
    ) {
        val text = searchPaginationName.value ?: ""
        Timber.d("onQueryTextChange text $text")
        ContactPagingSource(contactDao, query = text, sort = enumVal)
    }
        .flow
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

And now in fragment

```
private fun initRecyclerView(){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.randomContactPostFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
                Timber.d("Pagination in contacts screen --> $pagingData")
                contactAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my room query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ContactLocalModel WHERE name LIKE '%'||:query||'%' " +
        "OR pttNo LIKE :query " +
        "OR furigana LIKE :query ORDER BY " +
        "CASE WHEN :isOrderByName = 1 THEN LOWER(name) END ASC, " +
        "CASE WHEN :isOrderByName = 0 THEN  pttNo END ASC, " +
        "id ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset "
)
suspend fun getContactPagination(limit: Int, offset: Int, query: String, isOrderByName: Boolean? = true)
: List<ContactLocalModel>
```

I have opened the contact screen from web am pushing some data and it gets inserted into the **room db**. When the db is having change the screen need to refresh. How to do that ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own `PagingSource` rather than using the `room-paging` artifact and Room's built in support for returning a `LiveData<PagingData<ContactLocalModel>>` directly?

Comment: There is no particular reason for not using room - paging does room-paging will resolve this issue ?